# Migration from Sybase to IBM-DB2 or Oracle?

Tags: oracle, migration, db2, sybase

We are planning to modernize our robust power builder /sybase application , that has around 500+ stored procedures,300+ tables. PB application produces 300+ reports,nothing but datawindows which has no PDF printing facility.We are debating whether our new modern database must be DB2 or Oracle ? Both database is legally bought and available for use with our company. Any thoughts ? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you modernizing a "robust" application, and why platform migration is part of modernization?

Comment: Initial release of Sybase was 1987, Oracle started 1979 and DB2 was developed in the 70's - why do you think Oracle or BD2 are more "modern" than Sybase?

Comment: Application is 20+ years old and Sybase ASE may not support by 2025 (not sure of exact dates) and hence management want to go on web based solution. As DB2 and Oracle are already avaible with company, they are thinking about these two databases. You are absolutely correct - "modern" is not the right word may be, but that is how we are addressing LOL

Comment: Decisions like these are rarely based on technical matters alone. Budgets, licensing, skills-availability-and-price, cloud pricing, vendor-lock-in-protection are often  more decisive factors. Technically, migrating from Sybase to SQL-Server should be "easier", but you've not mentioned that RDBMS.

Comment: I agree about other decisive factors. Thanks and yes  SQL Server is easier but our company is IBMs workshop. We have several successful DB2 projects running now. Hence, the discussion on database migration is on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little bit on the platform you intend to use. Oracle on AIX is a pain, since this is the most neglected (by Oracle) platform the database is running on. On Linux I would tend to use Oracle, especially if you do not have to care about licensing costs.